# gitolite vs scm-manager

Tags: git

I have a project and I need to use a remote server with Git, What one you advance me to use, for example gitolite or scm-manager or another one ?

My task is not simple working by git and gitolite or scm-manager, but I need make this on Cloud !

Tkank you in advance.

Comment: Soliciting opinions is not what Stack Overflow is about. You've also given next to no information about your requirements. As it stands, I'd suggest git-over-ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Gerrit](https://code.google.com/p/gerrit/) - code review engine that also happens to be fully git-compliant server.

Even if you do not use it for code review (which you totally should), it is very convenient that Gerrit automatically provides you with ssh key management and access control for your users using its web interface - you do not need to create shell users at all.